# Can we implemented lightning:overlaylibary in SF1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

We are facing slds modal issue in SF1. So we are going to fix using lightning:overlaylibary. As per our salesforce document, it was supported in Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities.
We have tested it in salesforce app, its working fine to us. Unfortunately, they are not mentioned is supported in salesforce app.

url : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary

Our question is can we implement this at real time in salesforce app?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it is clear that it is not supported for Salesforce mobile. In other words its not optimized for mobile.

Now that does not mean it will not work. It may work but Salesforce support team won't be able to assist with any support.